# Getting Error ngrx Store is not an instance of rxjs Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store, rxjs6

I keep getting an error `You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.` in my angular project.
Basically, I am trying to access store state value in my effect like below:

```
@Effect()
getHoles$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType<GetTreeHoles>(HolesActions.GetTreeHoles),
  withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(getLastDocumentSnapshot))),
  ...
```

However, when the code tries to resolve the observable below, it throws an error.

```
this.store.pipe(select(getLastDocumentSnapshot))
```

I tried to step the code, and realize the code is failing in file rxjs' subscribeTo.js:

```
if (result instanceof Observable_1.Observable) {
```

This if statement return `false`. This if statement should return true because the store extends Observable. So the code goes to the else statement below and throws an error:

```
else {
    var value = isObject_1.isObject(result) ? 'an invalid object' : "'" + result + "'";
    var msg = "You provided " + value + " where a stream was expected."
        + ' You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.';
    throw new TypeError(msg);
}
```

I changed the code to be something simple like:

```
@Effect()
getHoles$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType<GetTreeHoles>(HolesActions.GetTreeHoles),
  withLatestFrom(of(123)),
  ...
```

However, it stills returns the same error and fails because of `of(123)`, which does not make sense to me.

I remove the line with `withLatestFrom` and the effect works fine.

I double checked, I imported withLatestFrom correctly.

```
import { catchError, switchMap, withLatestFrom } from 'rxjs/internal/operators';
```

My version:

```
"@angular/animations": "^6.1.10",
"@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
"@angular/common": "^6.1.10",
"@angular/compiler": "^6.1.10",
"@angular/core": "^6.1.10",
"@angular/forms": "^6.1.10",
"@angular/http": "^6.1.10",
"@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.10",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.10",
"@angular/router": "^6.1.10",
"@ngrx/effects": "^6.1.0",
"@ngrx/router-store": "^6.1.0",
"@ngrx/store": "^6.1.0",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.2",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1",
"core-js": "^2.5.4",
"firebase": "^5.5.3",
"rxjs": "~6.2.0",
```

This bug is driving me crazy. Please help me to resolve it. Thanks.

Comment: Try importing from `rxjs/operators` instead of `rxjs/internal/operators`

Comment: @MitchMcCutchen thanks. it works.